# ATM commission for cards from other banks in Serbia?

Tags: money, payment-cards, atms, serbia

What commission each of these banks charges for ATM cash withdrawal of dinars from cards issued by other banks?

- Vojvođanska banka
- Banka Intesa
- Komercijalna banka
- Alpha Bank Srbija A.D.

Tried several banks with Google Translate, but failed to find such info in their tariffs.

**Update:** And do ATMs in Serbia normally/always display commission to be taken before proceeding to withdrawal?

Comment: May be better for money.SE.

Comment: @karlson It's somewhere in between, but if you feel that it's more appropriate there, I believe you have enough power to move it to Money.SE, right?

Comment: I do not.  The mods can.

Comment: Don't take this as an exact amount, but somewhere about 1 euros + some small (less than 0.5% of the withdrawn amount) percentage.

Comment: @ldigas Thanks for a rough guide. Of the banks listed in my original question, which does it apply to for sure?

Comment: @yurkennis - I haven't gone testing it of course, but from what I'm aware it applies to all of them. It is the standard provision, more or less, when using an ATM to withdraw cash from an account belonging to a different bank.

Comment: @ldias Thanks a lot! Why don't you make it a standalone answer instead of comments? Definitely worth +reputation ;-)

Comment: @yurkennis - Didn't think it was worth it being an answer. But since nobody's pushing it, I'll just copy these comments into it.

Comment: @ldigas Thanks, great! One more thing if you don't mind: do ATMs in Serbia normally/always display commission to be taken before proceeding to withdrawal?

Comment: @yurkennis - No. You (from what I recall) can't see it on the printed note. The way to see it is to go to your account prinout and then see that you haven't withdrawn 100 but 112 (making up these), the 12 was the commision. Inpractical, but we live in the world of commisions :/

Comment: Based on my experience, the ATM never show the commission. Also, if you are going to travel throughout the Balkans it is best to keep euros with you because it is hard to exchange from one local currency to another one - always better from euros.

Comment: There's a company called [Multicard](http://www.multicard.rs/mreza.php?cmbJezik=2) here in Serbia (mostly in Belgrade) whose ATMs accept cards from several domestic banks with no commission. Their ATMs do show the commission before you withdraw the money.

Answer (score 4):

Don't take this as an exact amount but somewhere around 1 euros + some small (less than 0.5% of the withdrawn amount) percentage. Haven't gone and tested this with every one of them, but from what I'm aware, this is a relatively standard provision and applies to most banks in the region (Croatia, Bosnia and Herzegovina) when you're withdrawing cash from an account not belonging to that bank.

For example, in Croatia when withdrawing from different ATMs with a debit card VisaElectron (the one that withdraws money directly from your account, so, not a credit card of any sort) the provision is 10kn (1.31 eur) + 0.4% of the withdrawn amount.

Answer (score 2):

Myself I have tried only one ATM in rural Serbia: **Aik Banka** charged no commission for cards issued by other banks (as of downtown of Kopaonik, Konaci square). And it doesn't display any notice of zero commission, neither on screen, in receipts nor printed next to ATM.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Mastercard and withdrawal price of $2 per transaction (and 0.5 per declined transaction) has been set by card issuer and no additional fees is paid while withdrawing using ATMs in Serbia